# How to spawn a Armour stand with a iron helmet on in a minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a command that spawns a armor stand with an iron helmet inside of a minecart.

This is how to summon an armor stand inside of a minecart but I don't know how to add the iron helmet.

```
/summon minecart ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:armor_stand"}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by setting the `ArmorItems` property of the passenger object:

```
ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:iron_helmet,Count:1b}]
```

As a full command:

```
/summon minecart ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:armor_stand", ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:iron_helmet,Count:1b}]}]}
```

I recommend looking at the wiki page [Command NBT tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags) for more information on the Passengers object and other helpful tags.